# Error in opening files such as csv and txt

Tags: connection, read.csv

I set the working directory as below and saved files there.

> getwd()
> [1] "/Users/nina/Downloads/RCode_Data"

However, I cannot read the files and R keeps giving me the below message.

> DF1 = read.csv("KmPer1L.csv")
> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

How should I fix this?

> DF1 = read.csv("KmPer1L.csv")
> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection